# Can't step into caffe code in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, caffe

I'm just starting out with Caffe and it has to be on Windows because that's the OS I'm stuck with. So I'm following the directions on https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/caffe-vs2013-opencv-in-windows-tutorial-i/ to get something running starting with the MNIST dataset.

It doesn't work.  No problem, I'll step through the code.

Problem is when I start to single-step through the Debug mode caffe.exe, it will walk through the crtexe.c code but not step into main():

```
mainret = main(argc, argv, envp); << can't step into this function
```

I've got a pdb file and I've looked at the caffe source and with the Dependency Walker but I don't see any obvious entry point.

How do I step into the caffe code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pulling from https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows solved the problem.

Check the users group in case you need help:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/caffe-users

Check the issue tracker in case you need help:
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues